# Is there a way to install an older version of Android platform-tools?

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-manager, platform-tools

I have been hunting around for the afternoon to try to see if there is any way to install older versions of the `Android` `platform-tools`.  I have tried via `sdkmanager` and by the older `android` version but all of them seem to always link to the latest version of `platform-tools`.  I am trying to do this without `Android Studio`.

This also makes it difficult to create server's with the same version since it is constantly pulling the latest version when we provision a new system.  I have looked at the release notes and noticed that depending on the build date our systems have different versions of the `platform-tools`.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Questions:

1. Is there a way to download an older version of `platform-tools` either via command line or on the web?
2. Is there a way I am missing to specify which version of `platform-tools` you want to install when using `sdkmanager`?

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you could download old version,
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r27.0.0-windows.zip is an example .

change the version number in the link to get your wanted version. another example 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.0-windows.zip

Edited:
If you want to download specific platform tool via sdk manager, firstly **uncheck** unwanted platforms as below fig, and click apply.
[image]

Then download platform tool again like below fig:
[image]

Comment: I am looking for a command line interface option. 

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.2-linux.zip  works though.  Funny enough I tried this a few hours ago but maybe I made a typo when putting it in for 26.0.2.

Thanks

Comment: Use `darwin` instead of `windows` for mac os.

Comment: @Merk it's linux instead of darwin. I.e.., https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r30.0.4-linux.rar

Comment: Even though this works, the sdkmanager tools is not there. Which is disappointing

Comment: If anyone is looking for a link for MacOS, here it is - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r34.0.1-darwin.zip

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you want an old version of package tools, click on show package details and you're able to see old versions.

[image: package tools]